# CSS and JS no longer working on my Flask app

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I made a navbar using CSS and JS for an app I am making with Flask a while ago, and everything used to work properly. However, a few weeks ago I ran the app on localhost and found that the navbar was no longer showing up as it should. I don't know what suddenly caused this issue as I had not made any changes (that I can remember) to the CSS, JS or HTML which previously worked.

I have already used methods like CTRL-SHIFT-R and CTRL-F5 to reload the page and avoid cache issues, but they don't really seem to work. When I look at the network tab after refreshing the page with CTRL-F5 or CTRL-SHIFT-R it tells me that it's loading all the necessary files as far as I can tell but it doesn't reflect that on the actual page as my navbar is still broken. When I enter the CSS or JS file path in my browser it goes to the files correctly. Again, I am sure that there is nothing wrong with these files as they used to work.

This is what my navbar HTML is like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>main {padding-top: 70px;}</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <header id="navbar">
        <nav class="navbar-container container">
            <a href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}" class="home-link">
                APP NAME
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" aria-label="Open navigation menu">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-menu">
                <ul class="navbar-links">
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a class="navbar-link" href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Log in/Register</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/navbar.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Base HTML:

```
<body>
{% block navbar %}
    {% include 'navbar.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Part of the index page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<header class="masthead">
    <div class="container d-flex h-100 align-items-center">
        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
            <h1 class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase">APP NAME</h1>
            <h2 class="mx-auto mt-2 mb-5">TEXT</h2>
            <a class="btn-lg btn-danger" href="{{ url_for('auth.register') }}">Register for free!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Here are pastes of relevant files below:

https://pastebin.com/gRmGKAQE - the HTML for my navbar

https://pastebin.com/sVBuZrcG - Index page HTML

https://pastebin.com/PwYVZPed - My styles.css file

https://pastebin.com/BQNHcRhi - My navbar.js file

I hope this is comprehensive enough.

Again, I have triple checked that all the file paths are correct and my network tab assures me of '200' status codes for the following:

- styles.css
- navbar.js
- bootstrap.min.css
- jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
- popper.min.js
- bootstrap.min.js

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestions and solutions to this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the `url_for` is resolving your CSS and JS files correctly? The things you're reporting which don't work are using `url_for` so maybe the issue lies there. If I had to take a guess, those files aren't in `static` like you think they are for some reason. Maybe you moved something recently?

Comment: @ATLUS I am certain that url_for is resolving them correctly. When I inspect the HTML on the page once I run it the path is correct and I can put that path into my browser and it takes me to the content of the CSS/JS files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exactly same thing happened to me a few months ago.

The solution I found was that I ended up using flask_bootstrap instead of referencing the bootstrap stylesheet directly, this fixed my issue. I would highly recommend checking it out.

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html#sample-application

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's a shame to hear as I was actually hoping to avoid relying too much on Flask-Bootstrap and, as lazy as it sounds, don't really want to have to rewrite my templates. I'd like to ask: what's the least I'd need to do with Flask-Bootstrap to get the navbar working again but otherwise avoid using Flask-Bootstrap?

Comment: The only thing you have to change is remove the stylesheet reference from your base template and then import flask bootstrap in your __init__.py file and do 'boostrap= Boostrap(app) after lines where you configure your app. Just look at the link I provided. The change is simple. The rest of your template files will still be valid.